# Add multiple blank rows to datatable in a single shot(How sql inserts data faster than looping)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datatable

How to add multiple blank rows in datatable? My situation is like this. I have an sql query which makes a dataset as a result. It have 4 tables to join and about 100000 rows to shown. While showing result to user i need to embeded some fields conditionaly to the datatable. So I'm creating a new datatable with my required fields, loops through the first, creates new row on second. That i'm using for datasource of my grid. 
    But i could see the sql runs its query and makes resultset more faster than my loop(It processes query and create rows in RAM) very much faster than my simple loop(Only create rows). Why its like this? How can i improve my speed? I suspected the conditions checking, So i removed them. Still i'm getting same result.

#### Sample code

The query is so big and if i'm sharing that its against company policy. So i'll show some parts of the code which will explain situation

```
select ItemCode,Sku from tblStock ts join tblItemGroup im on ts.ItemCode=im.ItemCode
```

is taking to a dataset dsItems

Creates table dtGridItems

like

```
dtGridItems = new DataTable();
 dtGridItems.Columns.Add("ImgPath", typeof(String));

 dtGridItems.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(String));
 dtGridItems.Columns.Add("sku", typeof(Long));
```

Then fills that datatable like

```
foreach (DataRow drItem in dsItems.Tables[0].Rows)

{

 DataRow drGridItem = dtGridItems.NewRow();

if(drGridItem["ItemCode"]=="SHIRTS"){

drGridItem["ImgPath"] = Shirts path;

}else if(drGridItem["ItemCode"]=="Pants"){

drGridItem["ImgPath"] = Pants path;

}

drGridItem["ItemCode"] = drItem["ItemCode"];

drGridItem["sku"] = drItem["sku"];

dtGridItems.Rows.Add(drGridItem);

}
```

this was the way i was using. Surely image was not the column i was using. But if i need to explain the actual code i need to explain a big part of our software. Then only i can explain why the requirement came here.

Second Edit-----

Since question is still not clear

Sorry if my question is not clear. I'm not trying to copy one table to another table. I'm trying to fetch table to dataset in .net. My question is not the efficiency of sql server. My question is how datatable(in .net) filling works faster than my manual filling in dataset. Is there a way to create 'n' rows in datatable in one shot and fill them by loop?Can i set multiple column data in a single shot in datarow?

Comment: First you can't compare the performace of SQL query execution to a loop in the .NET.
Second, Please provide some code maybe we can help you speed up the execution.

Comment: I'm interested in the way they are allocating memory. In my code i'm making new dararow object of my type and adding it to datatable. I will show a sample what i'm doing

Comment: My friend you code is not very readable, for example where did 'drGridItem' come from ? and do you really need to create a new instance and assign it to dtGridItems on every row ?

Comment: Sorry that's a copy paste mistake. I corrected in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick SQL-Only way to insert multiple rows into one table from another is something like.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
INTO Table2(Field1, Field2, Field3)
FROM Table1
WHERE ...
```

Note that the query generating the data can be as complex as you like, you just need to add the `INTO Table(Field, Field)` line to pipe the results into a table instead of back to the client.

Doing this from .Net using a raw SQL command should take the same length of time to execute (plus the trivial overhead of sending the command to the server and parsing a response).

Of course, manually looping through anything client-side and performing an operation-per-item is going to be considerably slower - now you've got that same overhead for *every row*.

ORMs are also traditionally quite bad at doing bulk changes to data as they tend to check the state of each object and issue individual update statements (same as in the loop except often with more processing per item).

There are some ways to reduce the overhead (connection pooling being a prime candidate) but you're only mitigating the problem.

In short, if you want SQL to do all the processing in one go, you need to send it all the information it needs to do the processing in one go...

#### Edit

I don't know all the optimizations used by the framework but one of them is called Lazy Loading. It  populates data when it's used, not when the request is defined. [More details](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275932/Lazy-Loading-in-Csharp).

In short, instead of loading all the data, it populates the object with references to what data should be retrieved.

Eg instead of a rows like...

```
DataSet = //SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Age from Contacts

Firstname = John, Lastname = Smith, Age = 32
Firstname = Mike, Lastname = Jones, Age = 18
```

etc...

it populates them with:

```
Firstname = (SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Age from Contacts)[0].Firstname,
Lastname = (SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Age from Contacts)[0].Lastname,
Age = (SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Age from Contacts)[0].Age
```

Then, when you actually use the property...

```
String Name = String.format("{0} {1}", Data[0]['Firstname'], Data[0]['Lastname']);
```

It retrieves the specific values required. In the example above, it never bothers reading the age from the database.

Have a look at the `IQueryable` interface and how it's used to implement lazy loading.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I'm not trying to copy one table to another table. I'm trying to fetch table to dataset in .net. My question is not the efficiency of sql server. My question is how datatable(in .net) filling works faster than my manual filling in dataset. Is there a way to create 'n' rows in datatable in one shot and fill them by loop?Can i set multiple column data in a single shot in datarow?

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the great information about lazy loading. I heard that thing but i didn't try to understand that early. In a single comment you could make me understood that thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. I need to mark this answer as useful. But i don't have enough reputations(15 needs) to do that.

Comment: You should be able to Accept the answer (the tick on the left) any time. Once you've got 15 rep, you can also upvote if you want to give me a little more Rep. In any case, glad I could help